# magento “Quick simple product creation” section is not showing up

Tags: magento

I installed an extention for configurable product but it did not work for me so I un install this. Now in admin section I am not seeing section "Quick simple product creation". I think it is lost by the extention, how Can I get back this section ?

Answer (score 1):

I found it, in magento  "quick create section" appears only after the initial configurable product is saved. :)